# How to use @ sign as a string in Razor Syntax

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I'd like to use `@` sign as a piece of string, but it's getting detected as starting point of razor syntax, is there a way of getting around it?

Answer (score 12):

Use another `@` to escape it like `@@`